# Decryption only on a specified future date?

Tags: encryption, timed-release

Are there any encryption protocols or services that are time based. I.e I can encrypt something now and it can only be decrypted on or after 01/01/2100. Like a digital time capsule.

The only way I can think that this could be implemented is by a third party that publishes a list public keys - one for each future day and the publically releases the matching private key on the day.

Are there any more elegant solutions?
If not, are there any services that offer the above?

Comment: Just on the top of the related links. https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/606/18298 and https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/5831/18298 note that a specific time is more about calculation of the computing power...